# Enum within an enum

Tags: java, enums, nested

This isn't a matter of me being stuck, but rather I'm looking for a tidy way to write my code.

Essentially, I'm writing an event driven application. The user triggers an event, the event gets sent to the appropriate objects, and the objects handle the events. Now I'm working on writing the even handler methods, and I was hoping to use switch statements to determine how to handle the event. Right now whilst I'm working on the general structure, the event class is really simple:

```
public class Event {

    public static enum Action {
        MOVE, FOO, BAR
    }

    private Action action;
    private int duration;

    public Event(Action action, int duration) {
        this.action = action;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
```

Then, in another class, I'll have something like:

```
public void handleEvent(Event evt) {    
    switch(Event.getAction()) {
        case MOVE: doSomething(); break;
        case FOO:  doSomething(); break;
        case BAR:  doSomething(); break;
        default: break; 
    }
}
```

What I would *like* to do is something like this (though I would of course stick the switch statements into their own functions to avoid it turning into a nasty hairball of switches and cases):

```
public void handleEvent(Event evt) {    
    switch(Event.getAction()) {
        case MOVE: switch(Event.getAction()) {
                       case UP:    break;
                       case DOWN:  break;
                       case LEFT:  break;
                       case RIGHT: break;
                   }
        case FOO:  break;
        case BAR:  break;
        default:   break; 
    }
}
```

So, I'd want to create nested enums... like so:

```
public static enum Action {
    public enum MOVE {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT}, FOO, BAR
}
```

It's not like I can't avoid the scenario, it would just be... convenient. So whilst the above doesn't actually work, is there some similar method to achieve this? It would be nice if I could send an event with the action "MOVE.UP", and the method would identify it first as an action of type MOVE, and then further identify that it is specifically in the UP direction. That's just a simple example, it would be grat if I could also make longer chains, something like "DELETE.PAGE1.PARAGRAPH2.SENTENCE2.WORD11.LETTER3". The way I see it, I'm just going to have to use Strings and lots of if/else statements. Hoping there's a better way! (Oh, and performance matters in my case, if that helps)

Comment: I wouldn't use an enum to describe your events at all. Enums are best for a countable, constant set of states. UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT is good because they are unlikely to change.  MOVE, FOO, BAR feels like it should be easy to add to. Instead I would use polymorphism. (Each event implementing a doSomething that takes the game state).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps use an inheritance hierarchy for the Events?

So you have:

```
- abstract Event
-- MoveEvent(Direction)
-- FooEvent()
-- BarEvent()
```

It may make more sense to have:

```
- abstract Event
-- abstract MoveEvent
--- MoveUpEvent
--- MoveDownEvent
--- MoveRightEvent
--- MoveLeftEvent
-- FooEvent
-- BarEvent
```

If all the Move events have a distance, then pass that into the MoveEvent constructor (which will ripple down).

Answer (score 47):

I believe that in Java, you can simply nest enums, as long as your non-enum constants come first.

```
enum Action
{
    FOO,
    BAR;
    enum MOVE
    {
         UP,
         DOWN,
         LEFT,
         RIGHT 
    }
}
```

This compiles for me and gives me the behavior you were looking for.

Comment: interesting. and MOVE is not an Action. Action.values() just has FOO and BAR

Comment: Though, Action.MOVE.UP is totally valid

Comment: yes, but you need to know that. no way to easily iterate through all of the enum instances.

Comment: how would you achive something like this if(action == action.MOVE) getMoveDirection();

Comment: `MOVE` here is not really an `Action`

Answer (score 5):

you can nest them in an arbitrary order like this:

```
package nested;

import java.util.*;
import nested.Citrus.Orange;

interface HasChildren {
    Set<Enum<?>> children();
}

enum Citrus implements HasChildren {
    lemon, lime, orange;
    Set<Enum<?>> children;

    enum Orange implements HasChildren {
        navel, valencia, blood;
        Set<Enum<?>> children;
        enum Navel implements HasChildren {
            washinton, lateLane, caraCaraPink;
            public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
                return null;
            }
        }

        static {
            navel.children = new LinkedHashSet<Enum<?>>();
            navel.children.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Navel.class));
        }

        enum Blood implements HasChildren {
            moro, taroco;
            public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
                return null;
            }
        }
        static {
            blood.children = new LinkedHashSet<Enum<?>>();
            blood.children.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Blood.class));
        }
        public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
            return children != null ? Collections.unmodifiableSet(children) : null;
        }
    }
    static {
        orange.children = new LinkedHashSet<Enum<?>>();
        orange.children.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Orange.class));
    }
    public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
        return children != null ? Collections.unmodifiableSet(children) : null;
    }
}
public class EnumTreeNested {
    static void visit(Class<?> clazz) {
        Object[] enumConstants = clazz.getEnumConstants();
        if (enumConstants[0] instanceof HasChildren)
            for (Object o : enumConstants)
                 visit((HasChildren) o, clazz.getName());
     }

    static void visit(HasChildren hasChildren, String prefix) {
        if (hasChildren instanceof Enum) {
            System.out.println(prefix + ' ' + hasChildren);
            if (hasChildren.children() != null) 
                for (Object o : hasChildren.children())
                    visit((HasChildren) o, prefix + ' ' + hasChildren);
        } else
            System.out.println("other " + hasChildren.getClass());
    }
    static <E extends Enum<E> & HasChildren> Set<E> foo() {
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Citrus.Orange.Navel.washinton);
        visit(Citrus.lemon, "");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        visit(Citrus.orange, "");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        visit(Citrus.class);
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Love that I learned about both Enums and citruses with this answer