# Two dimensional enum

Tags: java, enums, state-machine, type-2-dimension

Are two dimensional enums a thing in java? i.e.:

```
public enum Modules {
    ATTACK(enum States{IDLE, NEAREST, NEARESTTOHQ;}),
    MOVE(enum States{IDLE, NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;}),
    SPAWN(enum States{IDLE, SIMPLESPAWN;});
}
```

Comment: Not in any sense I'm aware of.

Comment: Why don't you try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732710/enum-within-an-enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a little trouble understanding what you are trying to do, but might this do it?

```
enum States {
    IDLE, NEAREST, NEARESTTOHQ,NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST,IDLESPAWN
}

public enum Modules {
    ATTACK(IDLE, NEAREST, NEARESTTOHQ),
    MOVE(IDLE, NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST),
    SPAWN(IDLE, SIMPLESPAWN);

    private States[] states;

    public Modules(States... states) {
        this.states=states;
    }
}
```

(Note that to get the syntax I used I believe you will need to put States in it's own file and include an import States.* in Modules)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. As per [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1):

> An enum constant defines an instance of the enum type.

It follows that each enum constant, as it is of the type of the Enum, cannot contain a new nested member declaration. You could define all 3 of your "sub" enums as nested members of the Enum, and then access them like:

```
Modules.AttackOptions.IDLE
```

By the same logic (and the JLS allows this) Enum constants can also contain overrides for an abstract or default method, and hold their own "state", like so:

```
public enum Modules {
    ATTACK(0, 1, 2) { public int getCost() { return 2;} },
    MOVE  (3, 4, 5) {  }, // no method override
    SPAWN (6, 7)    { public int getCost() { return 1000;} };

    private final int[] vars;
    private Modules(int... vars) { this.vars = vars; }
    public int getCost() { return 1; }
    public int[] getVars() { return this.vars; }

    public enum AttackOptions {
        IDLE, NEAREST, SPAWN
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the sense you're thinking, but this can be accomplished more straightforwardly.

If those enums are capable of holding an array of `States`, you can set their known states at declaration time.

Example:

```
public enum Modules {
    ATTACK(States.IDLE, States.NEAREST, States.NEARESTTOHQ),
    MOVE(States.IDLE, States.NORTH, States.SOUTH, States.EAST, States.WEST),
    SPAWN(States.IDLE, States.SIMPLESPAWN);

    private final States[] knownStates;

    private Modules(States... knownStates) {
        this.knownStates = knownStates;
    }

    public States[] getKnownStates() {
        return knownStates.clone();
    }
}
```